# Unix copy multiple folders based on a specified CSV list using rsync

Tags: unix, rsync, csv

I have done some research and it appears that rsync is the only method that can possibly help me achieve this.  I want to specify a list of folders in a CSV which can tell rsync to copy them to another specified folder. My use case is that I have a root folder full of thousands of sub folders all with their own subfolders and files.  I want to copy a specified number of these folders from the root folder to another location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Your were close, but needed the --files-from command.  Your example seemed to want to exclude the CSV list. Anyway, this ended up working.

```
rsync -avr /rootfolder/ --files-from 'test.csv' /destinationfolder/
```

Comment: Actually, the $(command) contruction puts the output from command into the command line of the other command. It is equivalent to `command`, but it is easier if you need to nest commands.

Comment: This saved me so much effort `path/of/the/file`  in  `test.csv` will be appended after `/rootfolder/`
Thus 

```rsync -avr /rootfolder/ --files-from 'test.csv' /destinationfolder/```
will copy`/rootfolder/path/of/the/file` to `/destinationfolder/path/of/the/file`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

`cd $src ; rsync $( awk -F';' '{print $1}' $csvfile ) $dst`